# Is it true that the class of initial ordinals is proper?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

It is well-known that the class of ordinals is the proper class. Is it true that the class of initial ordinals is proper?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hint: there is an injection from the class of ordinals to the class of initial ordinals

Comment: Hint for a different proof: Show that every ordinal is an element of an initial ordinal.  Then apply the axiom of union.

Comment: Hi @Wojowu! Please check if I correctly understand your ideas. Let $h(A)$ be the Hartogs number of set $A$ and $\text{InOrd}$ be the class of all initial ordinals. We define an injection $f:\text{Ord}\to\text{InOrd}$ by transfinite recursion as follows: $f(0)=\omega$ and $f(\alpha+1)=h(f(\alpha))$ and $f(\alpha)=\sup\{f(\gamma)\mid\gamma<\alpha\}$ for limit ordinal $\alpha\neq 0$.